# What does F in FWORD stand for?

Tags: assembly, x86, definition, cpu-word, low-level

I am learning assembly language and I came upon the `FWORD` (6 bytes). I'm curious what the `F` stands for? There's nothing on the wiki page and also nothing about this on MSDN.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FWord

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26c4cbza.aspx

Comment: It stands for `FAR`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The letter "F" in FWORD stands for the word "far" as in 32-bit far pointer, which is the primary use for the FWORD type. A 32-bit far pointer has an 32-bit offset in the first 4 bytes, and a 16-bit selector in the last 2 bytes.

There's normally not much use for 32-bit far pointers, since most 32-bit operating systems make the entire 32-bit 4G address space accessible through all selectors. You might see them used in low-level operating system code to switch code segments since the CS selector determines the privilege level that the code executes, as well as whether the code executes in 16-bit, 32-bit or 64-bit mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I'm learning how to switch from Real Mode to Protected mode and gdtr(Global Descriptor Table Register) is 6 bytes.
`lgdt fword ptr gdtr`

Comment: @HrantCharchyan In that case the memory operand for the LGDT instruction is 6 bytes long, but it's not a far pointer. Instead it's a 16-bit limit in the lower 2 bytes and a 32-bit base in the higher 4 bytes.

Comment: @HrantCharchyan Watch out for misalignment if you use a C structure. The 16 bit length comes before the 32 bit base in the `lgdt` operand. If you aren't careful, the compiler will add two padding bytes after the length to align the base field on a 32 bit boundary. Either use a pair of "low"/"high" 16 bit values for the base, or tell your compiler that the structure is packed.

Comment: @HrantCharchyan: Updated the Wiki article, citing this Q&A as a source :)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it seems to be for "farword". You can find it on this website, section 12:

http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/DataTypes/lecture.html